# Unable to use python variables in html | Django

Tags: python, html, django, variables

I am using django to create a web app. I have run into a problem when trying to use variables from python in html. The variable does not show up. The app has a lot of messy code so I have recreated the problem including only relevant files.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')

def hello(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    fname = request.POST.get('fname', None)
  else:
    fname = "there"
  return render(request, 'main/hello.html')
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %}
<form action="hello" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

hello.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %}
<p>Hello {{fname}}</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what the "hello" page looks like(only part of the screen):
[image: html output(says hello but not "name")]

I want it to be able to output the users input.

Comment: You need to pass them in a dictionary as third parameter of the `render(..)` call.

Comment: You should take this opportunity to learn about *scope*. `fname` was defined in the "hello" function. It doesn't magically exist anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `fname` to show up you'll need to pass that into the render function. You're not doing that in `def hello`

You need to correctly return the argument into the render function like this:

```
def hello(request):

    ...

    context = {'fname': fname}
    return render(request, 'pops/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only reference a variable in a template if you include it in the "context" that is passed to the template. This is a dictionary linking variable names to the Python values they represent. The usual way to pass this to the template is as the third argument of the `render` method. So in your `views.py`, you should alter the final line to:

```
return render(request, 'main/hello.html', {"fname": fname})
```